# What are my options? - Separating out the UI

Tags: coding

I'm working on a project where the everything is driven from the a .dll on the server.  The UI and the business rules are all on this .dll

This makes it pretty difficult to debug.  My question is, I would like to present alternatives to allowing the users to the ability to still create customized screens without the UI and the rules being so tightly intertwined.

Can anyone offer suggestions or references to ways of splitting out the UI but still allowing ultimate customization abilities?

Let me know if I need to add further information.

Comment: Why is it difficult to debug? Just being a dll doesn't make it difficult.  What language/framework?

Comment: I'm used to the separation of layers.

Comment: "ultimate customization abilities"....sounds like the first steps down the road to dailyWTF material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious answer is [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), one of the best known approaches to isolate domain (business) knowledge from the user interface.

Essentially this pulls apart three main parts of a typical application:

- The Model, which represents the domain/business.
- The View, which represents the user interface.
- The Controller, which represents the logic required for the above two to interact.

This essentially means that you can put the model and the view in separate components (DLLs if you will) and have multiple versions of each. Some variations will also require implementing or modifying the controller however.

The actual details of the pattern can be fairly complex, but the general approach is used in an incredible amount of applications (up to the point where entire frameworks are based around it, and so all applications using those frameworks are based on MVC).

Comment: Is this web only?

Comment: @aComputerDrone No, MVC is used in desktop, server, web, etc. applications all around. I think it actually originated in desktop applications.

Comment: Are there any good books that you recommend for reading and research purposes?  We would be using Microsoft Technologies.

Comment: A good 6-page introduction can be found [here (PDF)](http://www.jdl.co.uk/briefings/MVC.pdf). For further reading I would recommend the Wikipedia page I linked in my answer along with the related pages linked at the bottom (and the articles related to it). Actual books tend to focus on technology: they exist for ASP.NET MVC, Spring MVC, etc. but if you're using older stuff (like MFC), then the general stuff is all there is.

Answer (score 1):

A universal solution is the [MVC (Model - View - Controller) Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) :

> Model–view–controller (MVC) is a
>   software architecture, currently
>   considered an architectural pattern
>   used in software engineering. The
>   pattern isolates "domain logic" (the
>   application logic for the user) from
>   the user interface (input and
>   presentation), permitting independent
>   development, testing and maintenance
>   of each (separation of concerns).

Depending on the technology you are using there may be alternatives (MVVM, MVP, etc.), but most of them originates from MVC.

Comment: @Mattieu - I'll as the same question I asked @Deckard.  Is this web only?

Comment: @aComputerDrone : No it's not. It's used for desktop application as well (MVVM for WPF applications for example). It just became really popular for web applications, as it eased the organization of code.